# ng-table work with user inputted filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have a scenario where i will be doing a page refresh of a ng-table but i don't want to lose any user inputted filters when the page refreshes.

The idea is to store the user inputted data in the controller, then push that data back into the filter input box after the page refresh.

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
  <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
    {{user.name}}</td>
  <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
    {{user.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
<p>name = {{ params.filter()[name] }}</p> //i thought this might be the way to get the filter data
```

example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/z98RLOX9AUOoX9c7x00d?p=preview

If I type "mor" into the "name" filter box, I want to be able to use "mor" in my controller to push it back into the filter after a page refresh, so the user doesnt lose any search filters they have used.

Is this possible?

Comment: After a page refresh, the data in your controller will be clear. You can think of using 'sessionStorage'.

Comment: hi, but how can i grab the value to store in sessionStorage?

Comment: You can use tableParams.filter(). Here you can show the filters with <p>name = {{ tableParams.filter() }}</p>

Comment: great thank you!!! If you write it as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: It's glad that can help you.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get filter data, it can use [tableParams.filter()](http://ng-table.com/api-docs/classes/ngtableparams.html#filter).

```
<p>name = {{ tableParams.filter()['name'] }}</p>
```

And you can use 'sessionStorage' to keep the search filters. Then the data will not lost after page refresh.